# Adding a line break or 3rd line of text in Rshiny valuebox?

Tags: r, shinydashboard, rshiny

I'm trying to create a valuebox but my problem is that the subtitle text is too long.

Here is my code

````
```{r}
valueBox(12, 
         paste('Number of Cars',':','City','is Chicago'))
```
````

[image]

But my Goal would be something like this

[image]

I tried using "\n" but it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work how? Try escaping it with `"\\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `paste0()` instead, I was able to do this using HTML linebreak code `<br>`. I think it might depend if you are using flexdashboard, or shiny. But this should help hopefully.

````
---
title: "Old Faithful Eruptions"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
flexdashboard::valueBox(42, paste0('Number of Cars',':','<br>','City ','is Chicago'))
```
````

[image]

Comment: `paste` vs `paste0` shouldn't matter—the difference is just that `paste0` has a fixed `sep = ""`

Comment: Good to know, I know there was a small difference, but `paste0()` seems to be my go to for some reason.

Comment: How do we add text above the value?